# IntelliJ IDEA：How does the template parameters change with the method parameters?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, live-templates

First there is a Method annotation template.

I write a method and add a annotation by the template.

When i change the method parameters，and how does the template parameters change with the method parameters?

eg:I added a parameter（String s） in the method parameter list, but the annotation template parameter did not follow the new parameter name(not add s).

Hope for the answer.

Thanks!

This is the code and graph:

```
    /**
* @Description: xxx
* @Param: [appName, usernameList, typeMap]
* @return: boolean
* @Author: xxx
* @Date: 2018/3/5 14:34
*/
@RequestMapping(value = "/message/send", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public boolean send(@RequestParam String appName, @RequestParam ArrayList<String> usernameList,
        @RequestParam HashMap<String, String> typeMap, String s) {
```

[method graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0YLq2.png)

[template graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BJ3de.png)

Answer (score 0):

The template is only applied when the method is created. It is not used for any subsequent modifications of the method.

If, instead of using the format you're using now, you use the standard JavaDoc format instead, IntelliJ IDEA will update the doc comments when refactoring, without any additional configuration. Here's what a proper JavaDoc comment for your method would look like:

```
/**
 * xxx
 * @param appName
 * @param usernameList
 * @param typeMap
 * @return 
 * @author: xxx
 * @date: 2018/3/5 14:34
 */
```